# fitting a wide table in centre of a page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to fit this table in the centre of a page. I couldn't find any way to fit this table on the page. Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \resizebox{0.25\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c }
\toprule
\textbf{MODEL} & \textbf{IH}& \textbf{NH}&\textbf{NH}&\textbf{NH}\\
\midrule\\
\addlinespace[-2ex]
$ 50\%$ &
$ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101  &0.00028 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.114 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018 i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.17 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$ &    $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$&    $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$      &$\begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$\\
\addlinespace[4.5ex]
$70\%$ & $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101  &0.00028 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.114 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018 i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.17 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$ &    $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$&    $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$      &$\begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$\\
\addlinespace[4.5ex]
$ 90\%$ &$ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101  &0.00028 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.114 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018 i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.17 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$ &    $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$&    $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$      &$\begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

 \end{minipage}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `\resizebox` inside the `minipage` environment. Actually, the minipage can be removed in such case, when double check and also found by @Mico. thanks.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}[htbp]
%\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c }
\toprule
\textbf{MODEL} & \textbf{IH}& \textbf{NH}&\textbf{NH}&\textbf{NH}\\
\midrule\\
\addlinespace[-2ex]
$ 50\%$ &
$ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101  &0.00028 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.114 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018 i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.17 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$ &    $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$&    $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$      &$\begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$\\
\addlinespace[4.5ex]
$70\%$ & $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101  &0.00028 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.114 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018 i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.17 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$ &    $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$&    $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$      &$\begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$\\
\addlinespace[4.5ex]
$ 90\%$ &$ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101  &0.00028 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.114 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018 i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.17 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$ &    $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$&    $ \begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$      &$\begin{pmatrix}  0.101 &0.00027 - 0.015 i &-0.000066 - 0.018 i\\0.00027 - 0.015 i & 0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6}i & 0.115 - 0.000036 i\\ -0.000066 - 0.018i&0.00101 - 6.78\times10^{-6} i&0.116 + 0.000036 i \end{pmatrix}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
%\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```